# "extensionKind": ["ui", "workspace"] extension disabled because it depends on ["workspace"] extension

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

I was having issues trying to get a VS Code extension working in a Dev Container on Windows: The extension in question is the [STM32 VS Code Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stmicroelectronics.stm32-vscode-extension). It was always disabled due to an error:

> Cannot activate the 'STM32 VS Code Extension' extension because it depends on the 'Embedded Tools' extension which is disabled.

Looking at the `package.json` files for the two extensions in question, I noticed that "STM32 VS Code Extension" is declared as `"extensionKind": ["ui", "workspace"]`, while "Embedded Tools" is declared as `"extensionKind": ["workspace"]`. Apparently, this results in "Embedded Tools" being loaded on the remote side, while VS Code attempts to load "STM32 VS Code Extension" on the local side, leading to the issue above. Forcing the extension to be installed inside the container & uninstalling it locally resolves the issue.

#### Question

Clearly, someone is wrong here, but who? Is "STM32 VS Code Extension" wrong for being declared as `["ui", "workspace"]` while depending on a `["workspace"]` extension, or is VS Code wrong for not "resolving" the dependency correctly by attempting to load "STM32 VS Code Extension" locally?